# Use pyautogui to click on-Screen board but no response

Tags: python, pyautogui, auto

I try to use pyautogui to click on-Screen board but no response

below is my code

I try to open on-screen board in admin too.
but when I run the code, mouse just move there and do nothing.
And I dont know why..

```
    pyautogui.moveTo(400,510)
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.mouseUp()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Could you explain why you added a sleep of two seconds?

Comment: because these code is in a while loop,I want them do like a script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to go to on screen keyboard 'Options' button and click. open a new menu and then click on 'Hover over keys' and change 'Hover duretion' in shorter and press 'OK'.

Now when you use
pyautogui.moveTo(X,Y) to any key on 'on screen keyboard'

then after 0.5 second automatic clicked.

Thank you

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: still can't press

Comment: Now check this answer It is usefull for you. Thank you for give me a response.

Comment: Ok its edited now, couldnt understand why webbrowser  was at all related

Comment: sorry i thought you dont open on on screen keyboard. So that. I am really sorry. and this idea is worked for you. Please inform me. Because it is works for me.

Answer (score 0):

use pyautogui.click(x=400,y=510) instead